# RegisterNatives failure

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I have a weird issue where-in 9 out of the 10 JNI functions work fine, but this new one which I just added fails. I've tried to move around this function in my list, but it still fails on this one (method II)

Any ideas? Here's how the list looks like:

```
static jboolean     JNICALL     Java_com_test_app_MyClass_JNI_AA(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint iNum);
static jint         JNICALL     Java_com_test_app_MyClass_JNI_BB(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj);
static jobjectArray JNICALL     Java_com_test_app_MyClass_JNI_CC(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint iNum);
static jint         JNICALL     Java_com_test_app_MyClass_JNI_DD(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint iNum, jint x,    jint y, jint w, jint h);
static jint         JNICALL     Java_com_test_app_MyClass_JNI_EE(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj);
static jint         JNICALL     Java_com_test_app_MyClass_JNI_FF(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jboolean bOn);
static jint         JNICALL     Java_com_test_app_MyClass_JNI_GG(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint iNum);
static jobjectArray JNICALL     Java_com_test_app_MyClass_JNI_HH(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj);
static jint         JNICALL     Java_com_test_app_MyClass_JNI_II(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj);
static jint         JNICALL     Java_com_test_app_MyClass_JNI_JJ(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj);

static JNINativeMethod gMethods[] = 
{
{"AA",      "(I)Z",                     (void *)&Java_com_test_app_MyClass_JNI_AA},
{"BB",          "()I",                      (void *)&Java_com_test_app_MyClass_JNI_BB},
{"CC",  "(I)[Ljava/lang/String;",   (void *)&Java_com_test_app_MyClass_JNI_CC},
{"DD",  "(IIIII)I",                 (void *)&Java_com_test_app_MyClass_JNI_DD},
{"EE",      "()I",                      (void *)&Java_com_test_app_MyClass_JNI_EE},
{"FF",          "(Z)I",                     (void *)&Java_com_test_app_MyClass_JNI_FF},
{"GG",          "(I)I",                     (void *)&Java_com_test_app_MyClass_JNI_GG},
{"HH",  "()[Ljava/lang/String;",    (void *)&Java_com_test_app_MyClass_JNI_HH},
{"II",      "()I",                      (void *)&Java_com_test_app_MyClass_JNI_II},
{"JJ",          "()I",                      (void *)&Java_com_test_app_MyClass_JNI_JJ},
};
```

The error is below when I call env->RegisterNatives(clazz, gMethods, sizeof(gMethods) / sizeof(gMethods[0]));

```
E/dalvikvm( 4573): ERROR: couldn't find native method
E/dalvikvm( 4573): Requested: Lcom/test/app/MyClass_JNI;.II:()I
```

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Here's the code for the class:

```
package com.test.app;

import android.util.Log;

public class MyClass_JNI 
{
    private static String LIB_NAME = "jni_test";

    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary(LIB_NAME);
    }

public native boolean AA(int pos);
public native int BB();
public native String[] CC(int pos);
public native int DD(int pos, int x, int y, int w, int h);
public native int EE();
public native int FF(boolean bIsFCCOn);
public native int GG(int iNum);
public native String[] HH();
public native int II();
public native int JJ();
}
```

Comment: Can you post the java source (MyClass_JNI) too?

Comment: I just copied your code into my project and there is no error in my logcat. If I rename the **II** method, then I get the error. Try to clean your project, double check everything and rebuild.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not closing out on this thread. I did exactly the same last week & I'm back to working state. I did lot of debugging in the DVM code base & understood how the register call really works. Maybe, that's the only bonus :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing a clean & rebuild as Robert H suggested does work

Answer (score 0):

Return type should be **jint** not **int**

Comment: sorry, that was a typo, fixed it, but doesn't help. What's funny is & I don't really understand is, why it can't register ONLY this function

Answer (score 0):

I most cases the package and name of the class calling

```
  System.loadLibrary("so_name");
```

and its method has to be exactly the same with the one one in with the native library was compiled